# Plotting multiple latitudes and longitudes on google maps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I have multiple latlng.

```
  var latlngs = [
    {lat:25.774252,lng:-80.190262},
    {lat:18.466465,lng:-66.118292},
    {lat:32.321384,lng:-64.757370},
    {lat:25.774252,lng:-80.190262},
  ];
```

Actually, it was retrieved from database using ajax response:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getLatlng.php",
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      // what should be the code here for plotting them on google maps
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr){
    console.log(xhr);
  }
});
```

I want them to plot on google maps and everytime I change one of the latlng from the database, the marker should also be changed without reloading the page by using setInterval. This is actually for gps tracking. I need help. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Everytime you fetch new information from the server you just a have to set the marker´s null `.setMap(null)` and then `.setMap()` again on the map. How to do both was described more then 100x times here on SO and the google doc´s are really clear and good for this point.

Comment: I suggest looking at the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers). What you will need to do is clear all the markers on the map and then add them back again every time.

Comment: Can u have a sample for plotting multiple latlngs on google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var marker=[];     

 $.ajax({
      url: "getLatlng.php",
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                map: map,
                address: "Something here",
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
            });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                  // Update Info Window Here
            });
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
      }
    });
```

Hope you have initialized map and marker before the ajax Call
And to update the markers you have to first remove all markers from Map

Here is the Function To Remove Markers

```
  function DeleteMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
        marker[i].setMap(null);
    }
    marker = [];
};
```

Just Call the function before Ajax Call

Comment: Yes, thanks. But how can I do the setMap(null) and setMap(map) again? so that the markers also will update without reloading the page

Comment: Where did the markers variable used ? I think, it was not used, because you use 'marker' variable to plot on google maps and not markers

Comment: Sorry For That Updated Now

Comment: :) Thanks for help